# ic_louncher Android Resource linking failed

Tags: xml, android-studio

anyone please help me to solve this problem. 
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin\AndroidStudioProjects\AsmaUber\base\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:3: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.user.asmauber.app:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.
C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin\AndroidStudioProjects\AsmaUber\base\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:3: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.user.asmauber.app:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\998b87f87efb4249c44cc3ef1681114a\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin\AndroidStudioProjects\AsmaUber\base\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debugFeature\processDebugFeatureManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin\AndroidStudioProjects\AsmaUber\base\build\intermediates\processed_res\debugFeature\processDebugFeatureResources\out\resources-debugFeature.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin\AndroidStudioProjects\AsmaUber\base\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugFeatureResources\resources-list-for-resources-debugFeature.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin\AndroidStudioProjects\AsmaUber\base\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debugFeature\processDebugFeatureResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.user.asmauber\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        420dpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Abdullah Al Amin\AndroidStudioProjects\AsmaUber\base\build\intermediates\symbols\feature\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0